# How to count divs on click in setInterval function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wrote this code to count when the user clicks on a square (div)

```
var run = false;
$(document).on('click', function(){
  if(run) return;
  run = true;
  setInterval(function(){
    $("#div").removeClass();
    $("#div").addClass("square").clone().appendTo("#container");
    $(".square").click(function(){
      $('#score').html(function(x, val) { return val*1+1 })
    })
  },2000)
})
```

but the problem is that when I click a square again, it adds one for each div present onscreen, I want just one point to be added.

Here is in action: http://jsfiddle.net/gwxfvesn/

How can I fix that?

Comment: Why are you binding an event handler **inside* `setInterval`? Every 2sec you are adding a new event handler to the elements. Why are you using `setInterval` at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because, while you are using setInterval, you (re-)add the click event listener to *every* square, not just the new one.

When you create an element, just chain on `.click`, so that it applies only to that element:

```js
var run = false;

$(document).on('click', function(){
    if(run) return;
    run = true;
    setInterval(function(){
        $("#div").removeClass();
        $("#div").addClass("square").clone().appendTo("#container").click(function(){
            $('#score').html(function(x, val) { return val*1+1 });
        });
    },2000)
})
```

```css
.square {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: black;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="width: 100%; height:700px">
<div id="score">0</div>
<div id="div"></div>
</div>
```

You need to add the click listener *only* to the new element.

Comment: This makes everything clear now. Thank you for the explanation.